# Can insertion sort be post order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tree, inorder, postorder

```
public class insSort {
int i,j,key; //j=1

public void rec(int a[],int pos){

    if(pos>a.length-1){
        return;
    }
    key= a[pos];
    i=pos-1;
    while((i>=0)&&(a[i]>key)){//swapping
            a[i+1]=a[i];
            i--;
            a[i+1]=key;
        }
        pos++;
        rec(a,pos);//post order
    }
```

can it be considered as insertion sort? or should it be in-order?
Is it a universal practice to use in-order for recursive algorithms?if so why is it so?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your use of "in-order" and "post-order" here. Can you explain what you mean? Are you asking if it's normal to do the work on the current, *then* do the recursion rather than doing the recursion to full depth and doing the work on the way out?

Comment: @JimMischel Exactly! Wont it be qualified as a recursion if the code doesn't go full depth first?

Comment: Nothing says that recursion has to go full depth first. Consider, for example, how you'd recursively scan a directory tree. You'd visit the directory node, then all of its children. Or a pre-order or in-order scan of a binary tree. Both are recursive.

Answer (score 1):

The example code in the question is a tail recursive version, which a compiler may optimize into a loop (no recursion). I converted the example code to C++ with some minor clean up. The initial call should be rec(1) (initial value of pos == 1).

```
class insSort
{
public:
    int a[8];

    void rec(int pos){
    int i,value;
        if(pos >= (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])))
            return;
        value = a[pos];                       // get value
        i = pos-1;
        while((i >= 0) && (a[i] > value)){    // shift up
            a[i+1] = a[i];
            i--;
        }
        a[i+1] = value;                       // insert value
        pos++;
        rec(pos);
    }
};
```